# List all entries not having a parent category with has_many through and join table relationship

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I try to get a table with all Listings not having a parent category

My Setup:

```
# Listings Model
has_many :category_listings
has_many :categories, through: :category_listings
```

```
# Category Model
has_many :category_listings
has_many :listings, through: :category_listings
```

```
# Category Listings Model
belongs_to :listing
belongs_to :category
```

I tried the following, but this seems to be wrong?

```
SELECT l.id, l.title, array_agg(DISTINCT c.name) AS Kategorien
FROM listings l
LEFT JOIN category_listings cl
ON cl.listing_id = l.id
LEFT JOIN categories c
ON c.id = cl.category_id
WHERE c.ancestry_depth = 0
GROUP BY l.id, l.title
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would make this much clearer.  What is a "parent category"?

Comment: Categories are in one table but with a hierarchy: ancestry_depth = 0 is a parent category.